# Creating a UWP DLL using Windows::Media::SpeechSynthesis

Tags: uwp, text-to-speech, c++-cx, speech-synthesis

I am currently trying to develop a speech synthesis UWP DLL using the namespace Windows::Media::SpeechSynthesis. I read this [documentation](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/05/23/using-speech-in-your-uwp-apps-from-talking-to-conversing/#1APSBKqZSUxColdc.97) and the Microsoft [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.speechsynthesis.speechsynthesisstream#examples) dedicated to the namespace. I tried to implement the namespace in code.

> Header file

```
#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <ppltasks.h>

using namespace Windows::Media::SpeechSynthesis;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Media;
using namespace Windows::Media::Playback;

namespace SDKTemplate
{
    class TextToSpeechDll
    {
        public:
           __declspec( dllexport ) void ttsInitialize();

        private:
           MediaElement ^media;
    };
}
```

> Cpp file

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Dll2.h"

using namespace SDKTemplate;
using namespace Platform;
using namespace Concurrency;

void TextToSpeechDll::ttsInitialize()
{
    SpeechSynthesizer ^synth = ref new SpeechSynthesizer();
    // The object for controlling the speech synthesis engine (voice).
    synth = ref new SpeechSynthesizer();
    // The string to speak.
    String^ text = "Hello World";

    // Generate the audio stream from plain text.
    task<SpeechSynthesisStream ^> speakTask = create_task( synth->SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync( text ) );
    speakTask.then( [this, text]( task<SpeechSynthesisStream^> synthesisStreamTask )
    {
        SpeechSynthesisStream ^speechStream = synthesisStreamTask.get();
        // Send the stream to the media object.
        // media === MediaElement XAML object.
        media->AutoPlay = true;
        media->SetSource( speechStream, speechStream->ContentType );
        media->Play();
    } );
}
```

I can load the DLL file and the function I exported. However, when I try to call the function, I get following error

[image: Error message]

I tried the example on the Microsoft [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.speechsynthesis.speechsynthesisstream#examples) but it some how doesn't work and I can't figure out why. I also tested the Windows Universal Samples available on [Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SpeechRecognitionAndSynthesis) which is an UWP app regrouping Text-To-Speech and Speech Recognition.

**Has someone experienced a similar issue? Shouldn't I use an XAML element when I don't have an interface?**

---

**Edit 1**

I modified the header file regarding the exportation of the function as suggested by *@Peter Torr - MSFT*

```
#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <ppltasks.h>

using namespace Windows::Media::SpeechSynthesis;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Media;
using namespace Windows::Media::Playback;

namespace SDKTemplate
{
   public ref class TextToSpeechDll sealed
   {
      public:
         void ttsInitialize();

      private:
         MediaElement ^media = ref new MediaElement();
   };
}
```

However, when I compile, I'm getting a new error on this line

```
speakTask.then( [this]( task<SpeechSynthesisStream^> synthesisStreamTask )
```

[image: Error Message]

I researched this error and if I understood it correctly it comes from the importation of the DLL function.

In addition, I call the function like this

```
_ttsUwpDll->ttsInitialize();
```

Which brings us here

```
void NxWindowsTtsUwpDll::ttsInitialize()
{
   int retVal = 0;
   try
   {
      retVal = _ttsInitialize();
   }
   catch( ... )
   {
      printf( "Exception in ttsInitialize\n" );
   }
   //return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you're using an exported C++ class instead of a WinRT component? Can you show how you're initializing and using this class? For example, in the code give, `media` is never assigned to.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT I edited my post (**Edit 1**) regarding the questions you asked me. Can you explain me how I can assign the variable `media`?

Comment: I believe `MediaElement` needs to be in a XAML tree before use. What's the overall scenario you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT I'm trying to make a DLL file. Do you think it would work with MediaPlayer element ?

Comment: "Make a DLL" is the *how*, not the *what*. Why a DLL, and not a LIB or an EXE? What purpose does the `MediaElement` serve? Is a `MediaPlayer` a better option? etc.

Answer (score 0):

In MainPage,I initialize the dll file and invoke "ttsInitialize" function like below code.

```
MainPage::MainPage()
{
 InitializeComponent();
 TextToSpeechDll* gf = new TextToSpeechDll();
 gf->ttsInitialize();
}
```

And In Dll.h file,I initialize MediaElement like below code,and other code as same as you.

```
MediaElement^ media = ref new MediaElement();
```

When I run the project,it works.
You can try it and if you still have issues,please show the details that you initialize your dll file.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, the snippet `gf->ttsInitialize();` calls the function **ttsInitialize();** right? I already declared the MediaElement this way. 
I suppose if it works for you, you configured the projects properties by enabling the _Consume Windows Runtime Extension_ **(Yes/ZW)** ?

Comment: Yes,the method "gf->ttsInitialize();" calls the function "ttsInitialize()" you declared in DLL file and I did configure the projects properties by enabling the Consume Windows Runtime Extension(Yes/ZW).

Comment: I implemented the method "gf->ttsInitialize();" in another class and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show more details about how you initialize your DLL file? And if you initialize the DLL in MainPage,does it work?
In addition,I create DLL file according to the code you first provided instead of the code in (Edit 1),did you also use it to test?
You can browse [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/how-to-use-existing-cpp-code-in-a-universal-windows-platform-app?view=vs-2019#to-port-a-native-dll-to-the-uwp-without-creating-a-new-project) to check the configuration of the DLL file.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my question. Instead of using `MediaElement`, I used `MediaPlayer`. Now it works, but I still need to figure out how to make the engine speak without limiting it in time. The `Sleep( 3000 )` means that the voice will speak for 3 seconds. However, if the sentence is longer than 3 seconds, it will be cut.
Here is the code of the program.

```
int TextToSpeechUwpDll::ttsSpeak( const char* text )
{
   SpeechSynthesizer ^speak = ref new SpeechSynthesizer();
   MediaPlayer ^player = ref new MediaPlayer;

   int wchars_num = MultiByteToWideChar( CP_ACP, 0, text, -1, NULL, 0 );
   wchar_t* texts = new wchar_t[wchars_num];
   MultiByteToWideChar( CP_ACP, 0, text, -1, texts, wchars_num );
   String ^sentence = ref new String( texts );

   task<SpeechSynthesisStream ^> speakTask = create_task( speak->SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync( sentence ) );
   speakTask.then( [player, sentence]( SpeechSynthesisStream ^speechStream )
   {
      player->Source = MediaSource::CreateFromStream( speechStream, speechStream->ContentType );
      player->AutoPlay = false;
      player->Play();
      Sleep( 3000 );
   } );

   return true;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question you asked. It may solve your ultimate issue, but doesn't answer the question. As such you shouldn't accept it as an answer. That's not how Stack Overflow works. It's about general questions and answers, not about solving an individual's immediate issue. This is not a forum.