# Speak sentence without time limit

Tags: uwp, text-to-speech, c++-cx, speech-synthesis

I'm currently developing an UWP DLL application using the namespace `Windows::Media::SpeechSynthesis`. I created a function which allows me to speak an entered text which looks as follow:

```
int TextToSpeechUwpDll::ttsSpeak( const char* text )
{
   SpeechSynthesizer ^speak = ref new SpeechSynthesizer();
   MediaPlayer ^player = ref new MediaPlayer;

   int wchars_num = MultiByteToWideChar( CP_ACP, 0, text, -1, NULL, 0 );
   wchar_t* texts = new wchar_t[wchars_num];
   MultiByteToWideChar( CP_ACP, 0, text, -1, texts, wchars_num );
   String ^sentence = ref new String( texts );

   task<SpeechSynthesisStream ^> speakTask = create_task( speak->SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync( sentence ) );
   speakTask.then( [player, sentence]( SpeechSynthesisStream ^speechStream )
   {
      player->Source = MediaSource::CreateFromStream( speechStream, speechStream->ContentType );
      player->AutoPlay = true;
      player->Play();
      Sleep( 3000 );
   } );

   return true;
}
```

However, the `Sleep( 3000 );`needs to be removed because when I enter a sentence, it is only spoken for 3 seconds meaning that if it is longer than that, the rest won't be spoken.
I tried to remove this line, but when I do it, nothing is spoken at all. No sound comes out. The extension of the duration doesn't either solve my problem.
**What I'm looking for is the ability to speak a sentence without a time limit.** Does someone had this issue before?

Comment: [Asynchronous programming in C++/CX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/threading-async/asynchronous-programming-in-cpp-universal-windows-platform-apps).

Answer (score 0):

You should declare a **private property** about your **MediaPlayer ^player** to hold it in case local variable "player" is released.

**in .h**

```
class TextToSpeechUwpDll
{​
//......

private:​
 MediaPlayer ^player = ref new MediaPlayer();​
};
```

**in .cpp**

```
SpeechSynthesizer ^speak = ref new SpeechSynthesizer(); 

char* text = "helloworld";​
int wchars_num = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, text, -1, NULL, 0);​
wchar_t* texts = new wchar_t[wchars_num];​
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, text, -1, texts, wchars_num);​
String ^sentence = ref new String(texts);​
​
task<SpeechSynthesisStream ^> speakTask = create_task(speak->SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(sentence));​
speakTask.then([this, sentence](SpeechSynthesisStream ^speechStream)​
 {​
  player->Source = MediaSource::CreateFromStream(speechStream, speechStream->ContentType);​
  player->AutoPlay = true;​
  player->Play();​
 });
```

Comment: I already tried that and it throws an exception. See this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56541000/creating-a-uwp-dll-using-windowsmediaspeechsynthesis

Comment: Actually, the code I tested worked.Maybe there are different places between us, but now I'm not sure which one.The first thing that comes to mind is the difference between the version numbers.So can you show your Target version and system version number?